# expo android app not loading due to table not found

Tags: android, react-native, expo, native-base

All of the sudden I'm getting the following error whenever I try to load the app on my phone. I tried changing to a previous commit (which should work), reinstall all packages, "git reset --hard", but all of this still results into the same red screen.
I tried updating some packages, but none of it seem to work.
I haven't connected to a sqlite database by myself, so this sqlite connection is probably an internal database setup by either expo or some other package.

It reads:

```
no such table: catalystLocalStorage (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT key FROM catalystLocalStorage
```

[image]

[image]

My Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "exp": "^45.1.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.52.0",
    "flow-typed": "2.1.5",
    "prettier": "1.5.3",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "remotedev-debugger",
    "start": "exp start --tunnel",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "color": "1.0.3",
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "native-base": "2.3.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "0.2.7",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "7.0.3",
    "redux-persist": "4.8.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "0.5.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools-on-debugger": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

This feels like a crazy thing and is really frustrating. Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue in the future: the problem was within my mobile phone. After I reinstalled the app and cleared some extra space, it was functioning normally.